# How to create an online Highscore leaderboard with azure and communicate it with Unity for WP and BB?

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, blackberry

I am pretty new to Azure and I wonder if is possible to create a highscore leaderboard and makes it work with Unity for Windows Phone and for Blackberry, since I have a game made for WP, I am about to make it avail for Blackberry but I want it to have an online leaderboard so people from different platforms can compite against each other.

If anyone knows and can tell me where I can learn about it, would be great!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows Azure samples for c# is here.](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/) However you'll need to use REST API to table storage services from Blackberry.

Comment: Do you know where can I find this REST API you are mentioning?

Comment: [Right here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj710108.aspx). Of course, you can use REST API at the both platforms.